# Abelian instantons for generic metric

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, vector-bundles, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

Let $(X,g)$ be a Riemannian 4-manifold and let $G \to X$ be a principal $G$ bundle. The ASD equations $F^+=-F$ are satisfied for $F=dA$ the curvature two-form of the $G$-equivariant connection $A$.

My question is the following: How can one determine if Abelian instantons exist for generic metric $g$? What are the conditions that have to be met and why most generic metrics do not admits Abelian instanton solutions?

Comment: Let $P$ denote the $G$-bundle. Then, for each $\omega \in c_1(P)$ there exists a connection $A$ on $P$ such that $F_A=\omega$. $A$ is uniquely determined if $X$ is simply connected. So, if $c_1(P)$ is anti-self-dual, then there exists an ASD instanton $A$ on $P$. If such $P$ exists depends only on the orientation and the smooth structure of the manifold, not its metric, namely the refined Betti number $b^2_-$. This is not a complete answer to your question because I don't know about the converse of my statement.